# XmlReader - how to deal with large XML-Files?

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

I was wondering how to deal with large and complex files in a `XmlReader`.
In my case it's a pretty complex structure and I'm not okay with handling all of this inside a single-method. This is just too dirty in my opinion - so I tried to split the method into a few smaller methods.

Therefore I started with the following code:

```
        // Create an XML reader for this file.
        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(fileText)))
        {
          while (reader.Read()){
             if (reader.IsStartElement(){
                 switch (reader.Name){
                     case "FirstBigTag": MyMethod(reader, otherNecessaryMethods) break;
                     ....
                 }
             }

          }  
        }
```

Theoretically this would work fine. But I experienced some cases where this behaviour results in a wrong state.

In some cases MyMethod is parsing the correct element and then I can't clearly see "where to end" so I can't leave the method without reading the next node. 
This would mean that I consume an element without handling it (because this is supposed to be handled by the main-method). When I now return I get back to my "main"-method but this is the point where my consumed-string would be necessary to decide which method has to be called next. How can I solve this? Is there anything like "reader.IsEndElement" or a "reader.look" - without reading the value but foreseeing the type?

Comment: Why not use a higher-level abstraction, like using LINQ to XML? `XmlReader` is too low level to use.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about this - I'm starting to use it right now :)

Comment: May I ask, where did you go to learn about `XmlReader` but not about LINQ to XML? I'm thinking maybe we need a canonical question here about "how to read XML in .NET".

Comment: Well, I've googled for "reading xml in c#". As you can see in the results nearly every page talks about XmlReader... So I thought this is state of the art and we have to deal with this very low-level-system. Also most of the threads in stackoverflow which deal with parsing xml-files talk about XmlReader aswell... LINQ to XML seems to be very unknown for me. Regards

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056%28v=vs.95%29.aspx http://www.dotnetperls.com/xmlreader  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056%28v=vs.95%29.aspx to name a few

Comment: Hints: first of all, that's about Silverlight. Second, it says "parsing with XmlReader". It doesn't say "best way to parse XML in .NET".

Comment: I knew that the thread talks about SilverLight but why should I worry about something which basically has nothing to do with the view? It doesn't matter to me if it's a wpf, winforms or silverlight tutorial as long as it uses basic .NET functionality. I'm used to stick for the first tutorial I get to see so I thought this is the current best way to solve my issues :) But to be honest I should have been wondering why this task is so "low-level" as you said ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the size of the file is too large to fit in memory, you could have the best of both worlds; read the high level nodes using `XmlReader`, and then use the high level abstraction as John Saunders mentioned, ie:

```
case "FirstBigTag": 
    using(XmlReader subReader = reader.ReadSubtree()) 
    {
        XElement element = XElement.Load(subReader);
        MyMethod(element);
    }

    break;
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll mark your answer as correct even though I'm using the LINQ-To-Xml Reader only now ;)